# jQuery animate method to hide & display left panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, show-hide

I'm trying to implement simple animation using jQuery. Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <div id="leftPannel" style="height: 500px; width: 200px; background-color: Olive;
        float: left; display: none">
    </div>
    <div id="rest" style="height: 500px; width: 400px; float: left; margin-left: 10px;
        background-color: Purple">
        <input type="button" id="Display" value="Display" /></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Display').click(function () {
            var status = $('#leftPannel').css("display");
            if (status == "none") {
                $('#leftPannel').animate({ display: 'show' }, "slow")
            }
            else {
                $('#leftPannel').animate({ display: 'hide' }, "slow")
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is when the left panel is hidden, its showing with the click event. But with another click its not hiding again. Why the else is not executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Display').click(function () {
          $('#leftPannel').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    });
});
```

Comment: @user1784622, note that in this way, you can also animate other parameters like `height`, `opacity`, etc. using `toggle` as the value

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Display').click(function () {
        $('#leftPannel').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I suggested the `.slideToggle()` method since you were trying `.animate()`. If you want simple `.show()` and `.hide()`, you can also use the `.toggle()` method.

**UPDATE**: to clean up some mess

If you are trying to use/learn the `.animate()` method, try using the visibility of the element; the way you were trying by getting `.css('display')`. This is a better way. Try,

```
$('#Display').click(function () {
    if( $('#leftPannel').is(":visible") ){
        // write animate method if visible
    }
    else{
        // if not visible
    }
});
```

Comment: well, my primary intention is to get used to animate method.

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to explain.